# Run time values while installig package using chef

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, chef-solo

```
package 'httpd' do
    action :install
end
```

When this chef script runs, there is no need to provide values at time of installation.

But there are cases ex: shibboleth-idp, for which during installation we need to pass some some values viz path, password etc.
How to handle this passing of values during installation?

Answer (score 0):

This is up to your packaging system, but assuming you mean `apt`/`dpkg` because RPMs don't generally do prompts during install you would use `debconf-set-selections` from your recipe code. Chef sets the frontend mode to `noninteractive` so dpkg automatically skips all debconf screens. You can either leave it will all the default values and configure things via `template` resources later or use `debconf-set-selections` before the install to specify values.

Comment: is it ok to ask for an example ?